# How to remove some elements of the data from the model structure

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

Below is the sample of my data:

```
> dput(mydata1)
structure(list(subject = c("E1", "E1", "E1", "E1", "E1", "E1", 
"E1", "E1", "E1", "E1", "E1", "E1"), block = c(3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 
4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6), condition = c("EI", "EI", "I", "EI", "EI", 
"I", "EI", "EI", "I", "EI", "EI", "I"), RT = c(271, 370, 469, 
409, 560, 1506, 544, 544, 978, 452, 340, 645), Item_number = c(1, 
2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
  > mydata1
# A tibble: 12 x 5
   subject block condition    RT Item_number
   <chr>   <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 E1          3 EI          271           1
 2 E1          3 EI          370           2
 3 E1          3 I           469           3
 4 E1          4 EI          409           1
 5 E1          4 EI          560           2
 6 E1          4 I          1506           3
 7 E1          5 EI          544           1
 8 E1          5 EI          544           2
 9 E1          5 I           978           3
10 E1          6 EI          452           1
11 E1          6 EI          340           2
12 E1          6 I           645           3
```

I could run mixed-effects model using lme4.

```
library(lme4)
```

```
mydata1_model <- lmer(RT ~ block + (1|Item_number), REML = F,  data=mydata1,  na.action= na.exclude)
```

```
summary(mydata1_model)
```

I am trying to re-run this analysis after removing the Item_number = 3 from the model strucure. I could easily remove it from the dataset, however since I am running multiple models, for the purpose of the task I am doing, it would make more sense to remove Item_number  3 from the model structure. Basically, I am trying to see if the patterns would be the same with or without this Item_number.

1)I am wondering if there is any way I could modify the internal structure of the model below to accommodate this change:

```
mydata1_model <- lmer(RT ~ block + (1|Item_number), REML = F,  data=mydata1,  na.action= na.exclude)
```

2. Would it be possible to remove more than one element, for example Item_number 3 and Item_number 2?

Please note that in the actual data, there are many subjects and of course I need this change work across all data set.

Thanks in advance for your help,

Comment: I don't understand. If you remove data, you need to refit the model. No? Why do you want to do anything with the model object?

Comment: You can update the model with `update(mydata1_model, data=mydata1 %>% filter(Item_number != 3))`.

Comment: Thanks @Adam for your comment, that was so helpful, so do you know how would this work if I want remove both Item_number 1 and 3, for example filter(Item_number != 3 & 1)? Thanks again for the help,

Comment: It won't work in the example you provided, as there are only 3 item numbers. Removing 2 will render lmer pointless. Better to just run with a standard lm in that case.

Comment: Thanks Adam for your reply, I actually have 64 items, I only included 3 here for simplicity. So, if if I want remove two or three items out of many items, could you please advise how would that code syntax change. Thanks for you help

Comment: `update(mydata1_model, data=mydata1 %>% filter(!Item_number %in% c(1,3)))`